# CSS boxes will not float from lower right corner

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-float

I've been searching for this solution for a while now... [bla bla... google.. bla]...

I have created an example where I'm almost there, but not quite:

http://www.mikael-sandbox.com/puzzlecss/

What I have left here is that I want the number 1 to always be in the lower right corner. This is the case as long as I have ONE single row of blocks, but as the row breaks, the row is moved up. I want it to stay down. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are these elements being dynamically added to your page?

Comment: Check out the edit I made.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the elements are being dynamically added to your page (even if they aren't), it would seem that the obvious solution would be to reverse the order of them.  The elements that would extend beyond the bounds of the container are going to always wrap below.  Found a couple links that may offer some insight regarding float and wrapping.

http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/33948

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm  See "Where will a floated element move to?"

**Edit**
Is your container fixed width, and will your bit divs be consistent width?  If so, then you know you can fit X number of bit divs on a row in your container.  With that in mind, you would wrap a "row" in a div, and clear it on both sides.  The sample below achieves the results I believe you are looking for.  I'm fairly certain that you will not be able to achieve this with pure CSS.  Floats just don't work the way you want them to.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="row_wrapper" style="clear:both;">
<div class="bit">10</div>
<div class="bit">11</div>
<div class="bit">12</div>
</div> <!--End row_wrapper -->

<div id="row_wrapper" style="clear:both;">
<div class="bit">1</div>
<div class="bit">2</div>
<div class="bit">3</div>
<div class="bit">4</div>
<div class="bit">5</div>
<div class="bit">6</div>
<div class="bit">7</div>
<div class="bit">8</div>
<div class="bit">9</div>
</div> <!--End row_wrapper -->
</div> <!--End container -->
```

Comment: Yes, my divs are generated, but it won't change that the second line should be on top of the first. I have read the links and there are useful information, but nothing that makes me crack this problem. Thanks anyway, I'll keep reading and see if I can solve this one.

Comment: I will try this solution later today. I generate these divs conditionally, so I might be able to squeeze these wrappers in, depending on how many boxes I have per row etc. Thank you so much for taking the time and helping me on this one.

Comment: I have now implemented this and after generating the dots in a very very weird order in php code (like the above example), it floats like it should. Many thanks :)